# Class cast exception while getting a String from listview

Tags: java, android, listview, classcastexception

I am running the following code `onItemClickListener` of a `ListView`. But it shows `ClassCastException` when i put the string at position arg2 in a string s as:

```
String s= (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
```

Code snippet:

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
       String out;
       String s = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
       //some code
     }
}
```

I am posting the stack trace also :

```
07-14 02:35:42.798: E/AndroidRuntime(412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 02:35:42.798: E/AndroidRuntime(412): java.lang.ClassCastException: bitcream.whats.your.score.Rest
07-14 02:35:42.798: E/AndroidRuntime(412):  at bitcream.whats.your.score.Intermediate$1.onItemClick(Intermediate.java:55)
07-14 02:35:42.798: E/AndroidRuntime(412):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
07-14 02:35:42.798: E/AndroidRuntime(412):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
07-14 02:35:42.798: E/AndroidRuntime(412):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
07-14 02:35:42.798: E/AndroidRuntime(412):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-14 02:35:42.798: E/AndroidRuntime(412):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-14 02:35:42.798: E/AndroidRuntime(412):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-14 02:35:42.798: E/AndroidRuntime(412):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-14 02:35:42.798: E/AndroidRuntime(412):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 02:35:42.798: E/AndroidRuntime(412):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-14 02:35:42.798: E/AndroidRuntime(412):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-14 02:35:42.798: E/AndroidRuntime(412):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-14 02:35:42.798: E/AndroidRuntime(412):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 02:35:45.468: I/Process(412): Sending signal. PID: 412 SIG: 9
```

Please suggest a fix.

The adapter code is :

```
public class Myadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Rest>{

    Context ctx;
    List<Rest> list;
    Rest r1;
    ImageView iv1;
    TextView tv1, tv2;
    public Myadapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Rest> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        ctx = context;
        list = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater lii = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(ctx.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = lii.inflate(R.layout.li, null, false);
        tv1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        r1 = list.get(position);
        tv1.setText(r1.name);
        work();
        return row;
    }
```

The Rest class is as:

```
package bitcream.whats.your.score;

public class Rest {
    String name;
    public Rest(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the statement arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2) returns String? If not convert them to String first before storing them to String s.

Comment: Post the adapter code

Comment: post the Rest Class code. DO you have getter and setter's there. also post the adapter code and look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition(int)

Comment: I have posted it @Raghunandan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list is populated by `Rest`. `public class Myadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Rest>{`

```
public Object getItemAtPosition (int position)

Added in API level 1
Gets the data associated with the specified position in the list.

Parameters
position    Which data to get
Returns
The data associated with the specified position in the list
```

So this `arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)` does not return a `String` and you cast it to String leading to `ClassCastException`.

So in `onItemClick`

```
Rest rs = (Rest) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
String value= rs.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Your type isn't a `String`, but it could be any `Object` (because of the `?` type, in this case it happened to be a `bitcream.whats.your.score.Rest`). I believe you want to use [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

```
String s = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
```

**Edit**

Based on your update, you should add `toString()` to Rest - something like,

```
public class Rest {
  String name;
  public Rest(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Comment: arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2) it itself return a String so if i cast it to String whats wrong in it the tostring() function also does the same i guess

Comment: If this `String s= (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);` gives you a ClassCastException then it is not a `String`.

Comment: Gets the data associated with the specified position in the list. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition(int)

Comment: @Shubhankar Yes, and it returns an `Object` - not a `String`. `public Object getItemAtPosition (int position)`